# How do I iterate through a list whilst removing any zero from the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list that I'm trying to iterate through while removing zeros(0) if any from the list.

The following is the code:

```
list = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(list)):
    if i == 0:
        list.remove(i)
    print(list[i])
```

Yes, the code works but raises the error `IndexError: list index out of range` as bellow:

> 1
> 2
> 4
> 5
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "M:/Python Workspace/PycharmProjects/untitled/scrapyard.py", line 6, in 
> print(l[i])
> IndexError: list index out of range

How do I do away with this error?
Thanks.

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: The other way is working from  the back, if you insist to use `for-loop`

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension to build a new list from your list excluding zeros:

```
lst = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5]
a = [x for x in lst if x !=0]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

You can iterate directly through a.

Comment: I was removing zeros so as to multiply the items in the list. How do I proceed to multiply the items in **a**

Comment: you have several ways of doing this. the simplest is probably with `math.prod(a)` (import the math module before)

Comment: I wasn't remembering that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With your code you go to remove an element and consequently the length of the list is changed. In order to remove any zero from the function you can run the following code:

## A way is this:

```
l = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5]

for i in range(0,l.count(0)):
    l.remove(0)
```

Unlike the other ways that others have proposed to you where you go to create copies of the list, with the code I wrote you you go to work on the same list without creating a new list.

Comment: Your code solves my issue. Thank you>

Comment: I hope I was helpful. If so, if you can value my answer it would be a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are iterating using `index` and also removing the elements thereby dynamically changing the length of the `list`. One of the approaches can be iterate through each element and remove it if it is `0`:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5]
for elem in list1:
    if elem == 0:
        list1.remove(elem)
print (list1)
```

Also note, it's a bad practice to use `list` as variable name as `list` is a built-in data structure name in python